# How do I prevent sites from changing the text when copying?

Tags: javascript, web-browser, firefox

Some sites change the text when copying it: add their own link, change the part of the Cyrillic alphabet to the Latin alphabet. I know the [Copy Plain Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/copy-plaintext/) extension
but it won't work, since it can't be assigned to ctrl+C.

I tried setting `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` to `false`, but for example [textologia.ru](https://www.textologia.ru/slovari/literaturovedcheskie-terminy/?q=456), it still doesn't help.

Because of this question, are there other ways to prevent sites from finding out that the text was copied? Then the text will be copied correctly and the site will not know that I copied it.

Comment: Welcome deevroman! Please kindly update your good question to make it clear that you are requesting a software recommendation.  It's a long shot, but you can try writing scripted commands for CopyQ (https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) to see if you can get it to work for your needs.  Also, you can try injecting the CSS code `pointer-events: none !important` into the appropriate elements of the live site (via your web browser's devtools) to see if that helps.